# How can I add an #ifdef DEBUG to Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, xcode, debugging

I have some code in a project which should never be used in the release build, but is useful when testing. I'd like to do something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // Run my debugging only code
#endif
```

Where do I add the DEBUG setting in Xcode 4? I tried putting it in the "Edit Scheme" under Run MyApp->Arguments Passed On Launch, but it didn't work. Alternatively, is there a flag already available for this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In recent Xcode project templates there’s already a `DEBUG=1` macro defined for the Debug build configuration (in the *Preprocessor Macros* section). You can test it using the `#if` preprocessor directive.

Comment: I'm working on a project that was created with an Xcode 3 template. Using `#if`, it still ignores the code. It's possible that I've removed it myself, I'm not sure. Do you know where I can set this up in Xcode 4?

Comment: It's a configuration, not a scheme. ;)

Comment: You are mixing up scheme and configuration. There commonly is no debug scheme but a run scheme which usually selects the debug configuration.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, the whole build thing is getting… complicated :) I’ve edited the post. @nevan, take a look at Build Settings and filter for “preprocessor”. You should see a section called *Preprocessor Macros*, that’s where you should put a `DEBUG=1` line next to the Debug sch—— configuration.

Comment: @zoul Got it, it's working now. Here's the process I used: In the Project->MyApp, under "Build Settings" I filtered for "preprocessor". Hovering over "Preprocessor Macros", I clicked the reveal arrow and it showed up my "Debug, Ad-Hoc, Release" choices. I clicked in the "MyApp" column for Debug and added "DEBUG=1". This automatically copied it to both LLVM and LLVM/GCC settings. I have to agree about the whole Schemes/Configurations thing. Xcode confuses me.

Comment: Note that this is only true of iOS apps—the Mac app template does not include DEBUG=1

Answer (score 6):

I usually add my `-DDEBUG=1` to the OTHER_C_FLAGS section in my XCode 4 project's build settings.

And yes, they can even discriminate between Debug / Release / ADHOC / Store builds.

Comment: I'd seen this, but because the choice for "Debug, Ad-Hoc, Release" only show up when you mouse over, I hadn't been able to figure out how to choose one.