# Live and Dev URL in an iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a number of iOS apps that rely on an API with both a dev and live URL. What is the best way to make sure that the live URL is always used for submitted to the App Store and the dev for debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debug configuration should have a `DEBUG` macro which you can test for in your code to switch between URLs. See this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257305/how-can-i-add-an-ifdef-debug-to-xcode).

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    url = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://api.example.com"];
#endif
```

Comment: More generally, you can define variables like DEBUG in your scheme and build settings. That way you can just use  `url = [NSURL urlWithString:APIURL];` instead of having all of that `#ifdef` stuff